# How to develop a wordpress plugin for front-end user?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to make wordpress plugin to gain the following requirements:

1. student can login and corresponding profile will be visible.
2. teacher can login and corresponding profile will be visible.
3. teacher can send message to student of a class or specific student or both.
4. student will be notified about their corresponding teacher's update.

I am new in wordpress plugin development. I need a guideline or a short direction about this plugin development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are various plugins for user management. Can't you use one of them, configure it to your needs and only extend its functionalities to your specific needs?

Comment: I tried to customize some existing plugin but failed. Hence I decided to start by scratch.

Comment: to start from scratch, i recommend to create 2 roles "studend" and "teacher" and a custom post type "message". look these 2 pages : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role